# How to write a template to list all posts with a custom taxonomy term

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have used the CPT (Custom Post Types) plugin to create a custom post type called Resources, and a custom taxonomy called Resource Categories. Within that taxonomy I have two categories/terms: blogs and books.

I have already figured out which file to edit: taxonomy.php

But I can't figure out how to write the template. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="content">
<div class="page-title pad group"><h2><?php single_term_title(); ?></h2></div>
<div class="pad group">     

<?php if ((category_description() != '') && !is_paged()) : ?>
        <div class="notebox">
            <?php echo category_description(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="post-list group">
            <?php $i = 1; echo '<div class="post-row">'; while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
            <?php if($i % 2 == 0) { echo '</div><div class="post-row">'; } $i++; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>
        </div><!--/.post-list-->

        <?php get_template_part('inc/pagination'); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div><!--/.pad-->

</section><!--/.content-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer();
```

What Works:

1. The page is showing up when I go to resource-categories/books. Good!
2. The title of the category "Books" and the category description show up. Good!

What Doesn't Work: 
There is no list of items from the category. It's just blank. I originally copied the code from the archive.php, which works just fine on Search pages, Author Lists, I think Category Archives, too...

What's wrong? I'm a php n000000b so I'm having a hard time translating tutorials/answers on the internet to solve this problem.

Comment: you need to loop over the posts using the while statement, look for a archive template, it will have the loop in there.

Comment: Thank you! But have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not your code, that is correct and should work out of the box.

Check the following:

- Make sure that the `public` parameter for both your custom post type and custom taxonomy is set to `true` in [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and [`register_taxonomy()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)
- Resave/reflush your permalinks by simply visting the permalinks setting page in back end.

This should solve your issue. If it does not, then you have serious conflict or bad filter in a plugin or in your theme.

Just a note, **NEVER EVER** run a custom query because something in the main query needs to be changed or is not working in the main query. Fix the issue properly and correctly, and do not hide it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use your custom WP_QUERY

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'resources',
    'tax_query'     => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'resource-categories',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => get_queried_object()->term_id,
    );
);

$query = new WP_QUERY( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ): 
    $query->the_post()
    ..
endwhile;
```

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: Create a new file called: taxonomy-resource-categories.php in your theme

Comment: I'm very new at this. Is that the only code that needs to go in that file?

Comment: @PieterGoosen What's your solution? What have I done wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be replacing the main query with a custom one. The main query is not working due to an issue, fix that issue. Please read my answer as that is in all propability the issue (*well, it is 99.9% of time the issue*)

Comment: Did you see my comment? I told her to put it to taxonomy-resource-categories.php, it didn't affect main query

Comment: You have a total misconception about what the main query is and what not.  The main query runs on each and every page load regardless. What is in the main query can be checked with `var_dump( $wp_query );` On each and every page, if you remove the default loop and replace it with a custom one, you have replaced the main query loop with custom one

Comment: But this custom query is only working with `resource categories` taxonomy (taxonomy-resource-categories.php not taxonomy.php)